# Calculate value based on choice column and value in other list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

In list A I have three columns; Currency, Value and USD value. In list B I have two columns; Currency and Exchangerate.

The currency column is a choice column and based on this column I want to calculate the USD value by finding the appropriate exchangerate in list B and multiplying this with column Value in list A.

How can this be done? I am new to SharePoint and much appreciate your help.

/ Sara

Comment: This is where the power of SharePoint Calculated Columns is not enough. SP is not Excel and SP is not Access. Workflow solution is the suggested path, custom UI with some JavaScript dat reads the other list with JSOM or REST code is the (programmers) alternative... if you go that route, use the Chrome Extension Cisar for developing CSR-ClientSideRendering code

Answer (score 0):

- Create a workflow for List A.
- Set workflow variable to the List B 'exchangerate' where 'currency' from ListA equals 'currency' from ListB
- Calculate 'wfvariable' multiply by column 'value' in List A
- Update the 'USD Value' column with the 'wfvariable'.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do it on real time, like someone suggested already it could work through a workflow but it will give you a static value to when that workflow ran, instead of what I think you need is a dynamic way to display data based on that information.

Is there a reason why you need this particular in a list? What you can do however, is export the information to an excel file, this way you can export data from both lists (Values, and Currency Exchange rate) to an Excel sheet and just by hitting on Refresh Data you will get the rates, kind of a report file.

Comment: I did as you suggested and exported it to excel instead. Thanks!